# Login with facebook and storing important user information

Tags: facebook

The facebook "wave" has finally hit me and I see that it's now time to integrate the wonders of the Facebook API into my site. I'm a little worried about implementing a "Login with Facebook" button because my site stores information about each user, and I'm not sure whether or not the facebook login system will also store said information. Any user who registers to my site has the ability to "like" certain pages that were found while browsing the site, and the categories of each page the user likes is stored and linked to his username.

If the user were to "login with facebook" however, and thus skip my registration page, would the information about categories still be saved?

Even looking at StackOverflow.com, I notice that all of my profile information etc. is being saved, but where? I used the login with facebook button so where exactly is my profile information being saved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you login with Facebook your site gets a Facebook ID and some other information (depending on what you ask for, but normally first name, last name, email address). You can then use the Facebook ID or email address to link it to an existing account in your system. If you can't find it, automatically create a new account with the details provided from Facebook.

Comment: so what you're saying is that custom fields may be created? Also, where do I go to create said Facebook ID? I may have already done so but I want to be sure.

Comment: The Facebook ID is the ID of the user who logged in. Facebook handles the authentication and says okay, here you have user ID 1234567 all logged in, oh and here's their name and email address. After that it's up to you - if you want to store extra information from that user then you need to record it in a table somewhere against that Facebook user ID.

Comment: Hopefully my last question, Jon. Say I have a `users` table in a database. Would I just read the information returned by the facebook API and store that information in the `users` table; OR, would I need to store their Facebook ID in some other table?

Comment: You need to ask for the email permission to get it, you don't get it by default. Also, be sure to check the [facebook platform policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) since there are some limitations for what you can do with the data you get for a user from facebook.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Yes, I understand this but the "extra" information I speak of would not be obtained during registration, rather, it would be obtained and stored during the user's browsing session. Therefore, I would only really need a username and email from facebook. My question is whether it is now upon me to store such information or does Facebook store it and I need to go talk to facebook each time a user logs in?

Comment: It's up to you to store anything extra.

Comment: That's up to you, I think that you should save the data in your own db, since you are already saving user data there, correct? not to mention that a call for the db (usually) is a lot faster than a request to the facebook api.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely exhausted my concerns.

Comment: This is might be a very late question, but I was wondering, if someone knew someone else's Facebook ID. Couldn't he just send it  (somehow) to my site's verification/login page and thus impersonate that facebook account?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Registration Social Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) that facebook offer in order to get the data you need from the user while they register to your site using their facebook profile.

Also, as @JonGrant wrote, you can just use the api to get the needed information from facebook, just take into consideration that the more permissions you ask for, the less users will authorize your app.

---

Edit: Plugin now out of date, please refer to [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.1).

```
This was plugin removed as of API version 2.0. It will stop working
on July 30, 2015. Apps using this plugin should migrate to Facebook Login.
```

Source: [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/v2.1)

Comment: According to your link: "This document refers to a feature that was removed after Graph API v1.0." So isn't it dead by now or am i wrong?

Comment: I referred to Facebook Login docs but I cannot seem to find a way to Register using that. How can we register using the new version of Facebook Login.